# What does the `str()` method return when provided three arguments?

Tags: python, string

[The fine manual](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) does not address what the `str()` method does when provided three arguments, as I've found in this code from `requests/models.py`:

```
content = str(self.content, encoding, errors='replace')
```

Where is this documented? What does it do?

Comment: The inbuilt `str` functions takes just one argument, may be the class in `models.py` has it's own `str` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reading docs for version 2, but looking at code using (or matching) Python 3.

[The docs for version 3](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) say:

> ```
> str(object='')
> str(object=b'', encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')
> ```
>
> Return a str version of object. See str() for details.

Following the link the following is said about the `encoding` and `errors` keyword arguments:

> If at least one of `encoding` or `errors` is given, `object` should be a `bytes`-like object (e.g. `bytes` or `bytearray`). In this case, if `object` is a `bytes` (or `bytearray`) object, then `str(bytes, encoding, errors)` is equivalent to `bytes.decode(encoding, errors)`. Otherwise, the `bytes` object underlying the `buffer` object is obtained before calling `bytes.decode()`.

Comment: Thank you. I am running Python 2 code, so I assumed that I would need Python 2 docs. I should have stated that.

Answer (score 7):

That's not the built-in `str` function. Look at the [imports at the top](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L27):

```
from .compat import (
    cookielib, urlparse, urlunparse, urlsplit, urlencode, str, bytes, StringIO,
    is_py2, chardet, json, builtin_str, basestring)
```

Kenneth has defined his own `compat` module for compatibility between Python 2 and 3, and he overrides several builtins including `str`.

As [you can see in that module](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/compat.py), in Python 2 it aliases `unicode` to `str`, so it pretty much works the same as the Python3 `str`.

Comment: Thank you. I find it rather problematic when people override built-in functions, for this very reason.

Comment: I agree, but I can see why he did it in this case. The alternative approach, taken by eg Django, is to use the `six` library - but that means calling `six.u()` etc everywhere.

Comment: Right, so long as the author expects to be the only one to work on the code. In all fairness, I knew that I was in for a world of hurt as soon as I decided "hmm, it might be a good idea to see what _this thing_ is doing". The library itself is throwing Unicode errors in the application that I am writing: `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 809, in text
    content = str(self.content, encoding, errors='replace')
TypeError: unicode() argument 2 must be string, not None`.

Answer (score 1):

To add to daniel-roseman's answer here's the [documentation and what does it do.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode). Since `str` in the stated code represents `unicode`.